# String Array to String without last index value

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am working with String and String[] in java.

I have one String[] and wanted to convert into String but don't want last index value in it.

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"1","2","3","4"};
```

I want new string as `123` only.

Yes, I can iterate arr up to second last index maintain assign the value in the new string. But is there any other way to this thing in the smarter way?

Comment: @Dhiral Kaniya, I don't think this can be achieved without iterating the array.I think you should look for the most optimal way to perform iteration. I personally feel, if you are using Java 8, then you can go for Stream APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think about three ways.

First one is using `StringBuilder`. This takes you full control with minimum garbage. **(I would prefer this one)**

```
public static String convert(String... arr) {
    // in case of arr is really big, then it's better to first
    // calculate required internal buffer size, to exclude array copy
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        buf.append(arr[i]);

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Another way is to use Java8 feature `String.join()`:

```
public static String convert(String... arr) {
    return String.join("", arr).substring(0, arr.length - 1);
}
```

And finally using `Stream`:

```
public static String convert(String... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr, 0, arr.length - 1).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    String[] arr = new String[]{"1","2","3","4"};
    String newString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length -1 ; i++) {
        newString += arr[i];
    }


    System.out.print(newString);
```

**Output**

> 123